# AJAX Preflight OPTIONS Request gives CORS Error but without Preflight works perfectly

Tags: javascript, cors, jsonp, preflight, netweaver

I have a SAP Server and a JavaScript calling web services from SAP.
So, till now I was calling SAP Web Services via CORS/JSONP and both were working where I would get a User ID and Password Popup and I would fill up the user ID and password and things would work.

However, I needed to send the user id and password from the code and when I do `request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic' +btoa(username:password))`, it sends a Preflight OPTIONS Request and I get this error:

> 401 Error( CORS Preflight Error)

Please find the attached code:

```
             function submitCRM() {
                 var url = "https://xxxx:8400/sap/bc/davey_rest_crm/zvertex_adr_cor?country=US&street=&city=tallmadge&state=oh&zipcode=44278";
                 var credentials = 'username:password';
                 var getJSON = function (url) {
                     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                         console.log(window.location);
                         console.log(window.location.origin);                            
                         xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                         xhr.responseType = 'application/json';
                         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials));
                         xhr.withCredentials = true;
                         xhr.onload = function () {
                             var status = xhr.status;
                             if (status == 200) {
                                 resolve(xhr.response);
                             } else {
                                 reject(status);
                             }
                         };
                         xhr.send();
                     });
                 };

                 getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
                     console.log(data);
                 });
             }
```

On the Server side, I have added the following parameters:

```
server->response->set_header_field( name = 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'
                                    value = 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT' ).

 server->response->set_header_field( name = 'Cache-Control'
                                    value = 'no-cache, no-store' ).

server->response->set_header_field( name = 'Pragma'
                                    value = 'no-cache' ).

server->response->set_header_field( name = 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
                                    value = 'https://localhost:44300' ).

 server->response->set_header_field( name = 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
                                    value = 'true' ).
  server->response->set_header_field( name = 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'
                                    value = 'Authorization,X-ACCESS_TOKEN,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers' ).
 server->response->set_content_type( 'application/json' ).
```

How to make Preflighted OPTIONS Request work if we have a SAP Server? Do we need to change any server files or it can be achieved through code?

Kindly help please.

Thanks
Sourav

Comment: The `Authorization` header makes the request [non-simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests), thus requiring a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. The error appears to be due to your server-side configuration. What **exactly** is the error you're seeing from your server?

Comment: @Phil you are absolutely correct. I am getting the 401 Error on Pre-flight OPTIONS Request. But i don't know how i can overcome this.

Comment: Check out this thread ~ https://scn.sap.com/thread/3787925

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the link. I already went through it but it doesn't solve my issue. I don't have an Apache Server :( 
If you have seen SAP as a server for Web Services, you can understand how difficult it is to find out the exact point where you will configure a rule for OPTIONS request.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help any further. You could possibly try the Apache trick for whatever your HTTP server is (intercept the `OPTIONS` request and reply with a 200 status). Best of luck

Comment: @Phil No Problem. I will see if i can find where the configuration of the HTTP Web Server is within SAP

Comment: The CORS configuration is described [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752/1ca554ffe75a4d44a7bb882b5454236f/149f40fa2c9b40599b2a61ee9127e20c.html).